# delphi simulate fifo with TStringList

Tags: delphi

i need to process a received data from a tcp link.the data are frames of hex string at length of 203 bytes.

i save them at the end of tstringlist

```
MyList.Add( input );
```

and from a second thread read the first string and process it and remove firs from the list

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
 var str : string;
begin
    while not Terminated do
    begin
      FTermEvent.WaitFor(100);
      if not Terminated then
      begin
          str := MyList[0];     
          MyList.Delete(0);
          //some process
      end;
    end
end;
```

The question is , is this thread safe?!

Comment: the answer is no, [but there is a threadsafe alternative](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/TThreadList_(Delphi))

Comment: Threading considerations aside, it would be more efficient to use a `TQueue<string>` instead of a `TStringList`.

Comment: small nitpick, don't use strings to store binary data...

Comment: Please read this excellent [primer on threading](http://www.nickhodges.com/multithreadingindelphi/toc.html). What you have is a typical producer/consumer case...

Comment: why oh why would you store binary data as hex text?

Comment: Consider to use a local database to store data then process them, starting from first recordset inserted. You can consider to create one service listening the tcp data to insert in the database, then a second application/service to process data. In this way, in case of exception during process data, the first service will continue to insert data and the result is that you wont lost any data recieved.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan because that's the way he receives them?

Comment: @dummzeuch There is a sender somewhere that is choosing to convert binary data into a hex string

Comment: @GianlucaColombo fifo is a standard way to process que.the database is stable but im worry to lose time on a lots of data inputs...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan your are right data are binary but  i must split data and save them as text in some databases, so i decided to convert them at first step...

Comment: Sounds like a mistake. Transmit as binary and convert once it has arrived. Also, if you need to save binary as text, convert it to base64 not hex.

Comment: why base64? sender is a electronic board and just understand base16! also the sender is not in my control.i just need to find a best solution to process data not change the whole protocol!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are afraid to loose input data using database, you can try to use TThreadStringList.
I imagine that your software receives data from multiple devices simultaneously (and in this case you should create a  multi-thread socked to make you sure  to receive all the data) if you are receiving data from a single device instead , you should make sure that the tcp protocol supports a sort of aknowlage system to avoid losing data or at least to report in a log, the data that your application has not been able to receive completely.

Anyway, TThreadStringList is a simple wrapper for TStringList.
It should makes possible to access a String List from different threads without any conflicts.
I can't test it but for you should be easy and quick to try.

The link:
[TThreadStringList](https://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=2167)